# Retrieving primitive data type from WebService in VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services

I have implemented a web service in VB .NET.

For retrieving the data I have created an object like this:

```
Public Class Product 
    Public idProduct As Integer
    Public state As Integer
    Public description As String
    Public longDescription As String
    Public idCategory As Integer
    Public price As Decimal
End Class
```

Then I create a List of Product object:

```
Dim ProductList As List(Of Product)
```

that is what my WebMethod returns.

The web service worked good, and returns an xml that contains a list of Products like this

```
<Product>
   <idProduct>169</idProduct >
   <state>0</state>
   <idCategory>32001</idCategory>
   <description>description of the article</description>
   <longDescription>extended description of the article</longDescription>
   <price>2.44</price>
</Product>
```

But, in some situation I don't want retrieve all this information. I want just return the idProduct and the state:

```
<Product>
   <idProduct>170</idProduct >
   <state>-1</state>
</Product>
```

Instead, what I obtain is the following:

```
<Product>
   <idProduct>170</idProduct >
   <state>-1</state>
   <idCategory>0</idCategory>
   <price>0</price>
</Product>
```

Only the String fileds (description and longDescription) are removed from the xml, while all the field that in the object are defined as Integer or Decimal, also If I do not set any value, automatically are setted to zero.

**EDIT:**

The code I use for create the object is the following:

```
For Each row In table.Rows
   p = New Product()
   p.idProduct= Utilities.DBNullToInvalidInt(row.Item("ID"))
   p.state= Utilities.DBNullToInvalidInt(row.Item("State"))
   If p.FileStateID = 0 Then
      p.idCategory= Utilities.DBNullToInvalidInt(row.Item("idCategory"))
      p.description= Utilities.DBNullToVoidString(row.Item("Description"))
      p.longDescription = Utilities.DBNullToVoidString(row.Item("ExtendedDescription"))
      p.price= row.Item("Price")
   End If

   ProductList .Add(p)

Next
```

where table contains the result of my SQL query

Comment: Please post your web service code where you are reducing the number of fields returned, specifically the example you gave where you are getting four fields back when you only expect two.

Comment: I'm simpling letting all members of my class unassigned (except idProduct and state)

Comment: You get these strings by XmlSerializer ?

Answer (score 0):

Make the fields that may be omitted `Nullable`, like this:

```
Public Class Product 
    Public idProduct As Integer
    Public state As Integer
    Public description As String
    Public longDescription As String
    Public idCategory As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public price As Nullable(Of Decimal)
End Class
```

Now `idCategory` and `price` will default to `Nothing` (i.e. `null`).

Comment: Thank you @Karl, but the the client should always call the same WS, The logic of whether retrieve all product details or nly id and state depends on the state value(which is stored in the database).
So, I can have mixed "type" of xml product

Comment: @Joseph82 - does making `idCategory` and `price` `Nullable(Of)` not work?

Comment: I obtain an error on p.price= row.Item("Price"). "specified cast not valid". While for the Integer filed I obtain in the xml this: <idCategory xsi:nil="true"/>